# Marketing Cloud measure doesn't capture data from sends prior to the last

Tags: marketing-cloud

Using an automation, I send an email every 4 days. I wrote a measure to capture who clicked on a particular link; to do so I used Click as the Event Source and set conditions on the name of the link and the name of the email. I also created a data filter and a filter automation. However, when the automation runs, only the results of the last send are captured, whereas I would like to track data for all the sends. I also tried to add conditions on the Click Date, but if I exclude the last send the tracking count is 0. How can I capture also the data for the previous sends?

Comment: Hi. Can you share a screenshot of your measure?